# How to validate Keycloak webhook request?

Tags: python, flask, request, keycloak, webhooks

I'm implementing an endpoint to receive events from Keycloak using a webhook, but I don't know how to validate this request.

I see that the request contains a header "X-Keycloak-Signature". Also, I set a WEBHOOK_SECRET. It seems I somehow need to generate this signature from the request and the secret and then compare them. So it looks like this:

```
import os
import hashlib

from flask import abort, request


def validate_keycloak_signature(f):

    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        secret = os.getenv("WEBHOOK_SECRET")
        method = request.method
        uri = request.url
        body = request.get_data(as_text=True)
        smub = secret + method + uri + body
        h = hashlib.sha256(smub.encode("utf-8")).hexdigest()
        signature = request.headers.get("X-Keycloak-Signature")
        if h != signature:
            return abort(403)
        return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
    
    return wrapper
```

However, I don't know the algorithm. Here, I tried this one:

```
1. Create a string that concatenates together the following: Client secret + http method + URI + request body (if present)
2. Create a SHA-256 hash of the resulting string.
3. Compare the hash value to the signature. If they're equal then this request has passed validation.
```

But it doesn't work. Does anybody has any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I realized that this signature is generated not by Keycloak itself, but by Phasetwo which provides a webhook plugin for me.

So that I just looked into its code and found out the algorithm.

That is how to generate signature to validate it:

```
def validate_keycloak_signature(f):
    ...
        secret = os.getenv("WEBHOOK_SECRET")
        body = request.data
        control_signature = hmac.new(
            key=bytes(secret, "utf-8"),
            msg=body,
            digestmod=hashlib.sha256
        ).hexdigest()
    ...
```